# Postfix Multiple Sender bcc

Tags: email, debian, postfix

I am trying to configure postfix to send mails to multiple email address using sender_bcc, if I send caterpillar@domain.com it should send a bcc mail to xyz@domain.com as well as abc@gmail.com.

Example :

caterpillar@domain.com ----> xyz@domain.com,
caterpillar@domain.com ----> abc@gmail.com

how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never actually configured postfix but just found this tutorial and I am not sure if it will help you... the last comment on the site shows using more than one forwarder by separating emails by a comma

[Tutorial Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/#comment-41974)

This page use `virtual_alias_maps` instead *_bcc parameter as you proposed in question. So I was wondering if you could bcc to one email and then use postfix virtual to then forward to the addresses you require?

hope that helps

Comment: Problem Fixed, Thanks for the reply. 

Solution:
create a file in /opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/virtual.tab. Postmap the file. Follow as below. Add the email address caterpillar@domain.com  123@domain.com (here 123@domain.com is not a mailbox or distbox its just a dummy address). In virtual.tab add the email address to which account the mail copies to be sent.

123@domain.com    abc@domain@.com, xyz@gmail.com, hdg@hotmail.com

Add this line to main.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:ldap:/opt/zimbra/conf/ldap-vam.cf,hash:/opt/zimbra/postfix/conf/virtual.tab

Comment: Thanks for putting the solution...thanks for the reply to