# One public contact email, more than one customer service representative?

Tags: email

I'm working on a website for a client and we need to put contact info on the site.  In their case, they have two people who will respond to customer inquiries.

Instead of putting both of their emails on the website I set up mail forwarding from a contact@domain.com and display it on the website.

So as it is, a customer emails contact@domain.com and it is forwarded on to both rep1@domain.com and rep2@domain.com.

Then one or the other can reply with their own email and their own name, giving it a more personal touch, boosting the customers confidence that it's an honest business.

The problem with this is that they would need to be very careful to not double team a client, both replying without knowing the other is too.

Is there some way to set it up so that the other rep gets notified too? Something like a "Reply-To/Bcc" header.

Comment: You can have the mail server do an automatic bcc for you. Postfix can do it. It has already been answered http://serverfault.com/questions/32087/postfix-multiple-sender-bcc

Comment: What email platform/products are you using in your environment?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a Support Ticket Tracking System like OTRS, OSTicket etc.? These Systems can be configured to receive mails from  a specific address. The system will then automaticaly create a support ticket, which is seen by the whole support Team. like this everybody in the team can see which case has not yet been taken care off.

And, another advantage: if supporter1 took  the case, but is sick the next few weeks,  supporter2 can look over the open cases and react if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is the shared IMAP folder of `contact@domain.tld` accessible for both `rep1@domain.tld` and `rep2@domain.tld`. When some person see message in that folder, he move it to its own working folder. When reply will be sended it should contain `contact@domain.tld` as `FROM` and `repX@domain.tld` as `REPLY-TO` - just to keep conversation with the same worker all the time.